# How can i set the same IBAction to multiple buttons?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to link multiple buttons with the same `IBAction`, to run similar but different code. The code is to set an image that was clicked on another view controller into the `UIImageView` under the button. 
All the buttons link to the same view controller but with a different segue.

I tried to write a if statements but I didn't seem to have it right. I have named each corresponding `UIImage` view: `technologyImageViewTwo`, `technologyImageViewThree` ...etc

below is the code I used for the first button which works with the corresponding `UIImageView` named `technologyImageView`

```
@IBAction func setTechnology(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        dismiss(animated: true) {

            if let technology = segue.identifier{
                self.persona.technology = technology
                self.technologyView.technologyImageView.image = UIImage(named: technology)
            }

            //animating scale up of image
            let scaleUp = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.1, y:0.1)
            self.technologyView.technologyImageView.transform = scaleUp
            self.technologyView.technologyImageView.alpha = 0

            //animating bounce effect 
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: [], animations: {
                self.technologyView.technologyImageView.transform = .identity
                self.technologyView.technologyImageView.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
        }
```

I expect that each button should go to the segued view controller and the image selected will show up under the corresponding button. E.g if I click on the button 'Technology 2' and choose an image, the image shows up in the `UIImageview` named `technologyImageViewTwo`.

Comment: You can use tag, set tag for each button and check that on the `IBAction` method and make decision based on number of tag

Comment: @ArashEtemad How do I go about this? Sorry, I'm still quite new to swift

Comment: Connect an outlet to each button and switch over `sender`. It's the same as tags but without magic numbers. Or declare separate `IBActions` methods and move the common implementation to a *different* method.

Comment: @Toto What became of this question?

Comment: @Adrian I realised my issue was with the way I connected the buttons, the code way linked with a segue rather than a button, I had to rethink of the way to order my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options, that you can choose from:

**Option 1:**

This option would be more preferred, that is to use the tag property on the component, this will allow you to identify the index of the button when it has been actioned.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag

```swift
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
         var imageView: UIImageView!
         let index = (sender as? UIView)?.tag ?? 0

         switch index {
         case 1:
             persona.technology = <#T##String#>
             imageView = technologyView.technologyImageViewTwo
         case 2:
             persona.technology = <#T##String#>
             imageView = technologyView.technologyImageViewThree
         default:
             persona.technology = <#T##String#>
             imageView = technologyView.technologyImageView
        }

        if let technology = persona.technology {
             imageView.image = UIImage(named: technology)
        }

        //animating scale up of image
        let scaleUp = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.1, y:0.1)
        imageView.transform = scaleUp
        imageView.alpha = 0

        //animating bounce effect
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: [], animations: {
            imageView.transform = .identity
            imageView.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

If you want to continue with the code you have then you could use a segue identifier that contains components that you can be split out and enable you to identify them more efficiently:

> segueIdentifier-1, segueIdentifier-2, segueIdentifier-3

```swift
func setTechnology(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
     dismiss(animated: true) {

        var imageView: UIImageView!
        let identifierComponents = segue.identifier?.components(separatedBy: "-")
        let index = Int(identifierComponents?.last ?? "0")

        switch index {
        case 1:
            imageView = technologyView.technologyImageViewTwo
        case 2:
            imageView = technologyView.technologyImageViewThree
        default:
            imageView = technologyView.technologyImageView
        }

        if let technology = identifierComponents?.first {
            self.persona.technology = technology
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: technology)
        }

        //animating scale up of image
        let scaleUp = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.1, y:0.1)
        imageView.transform = scaleUp
        imageView.alpha = 0

        //animating bounce effect
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: [], animations: {
            imageView.transform = .identity
            imageView.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried option 2 but it just seems to only update the first image, no matter what which button I press. How can I go about the first option? Sorry, quite new to Swift

Comment: Can you provide me with the segue example you have tried for option 2.

Comment: Given a IBAction with tagging example.

Comment: Don't know what happened but half my answer disappeared!, Fixed

Comment: I don't think I explained this well, sorry. My issue is based between 2 different view controllers. The 1st view controller with the technology button and the 2nd view controller with the image buttons. the code I originally showed above is linked as a segue closure for the images in the 2nd view controller and not the buttons in the 1st view controller. So the code runs when the image button in the second view controller is pressed. The technology buttons only have a segue linking to the second view controller with the image buttons. So I guess I need to re-order my code?

Comment: That's fine then I will update my answer and you should use the second option.

Comment: I tried your second version but i get the following error in the `let technology = identifierComponents?.first` part

"Cannot assign value of type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') to type 'String'"

Comment: Thank you, it builds but still only updates the first image, I get the following warning "Variable 'identifierComponents' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant" 
"Variable 'index' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant"

Comment: Can you send me a segue identifier example

Comment: I'm not sure how to show it, but i've linkes my xcode project here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OE4sf8pJF_DYl6OyngdvJnsDjO36LPPR

If you go to the main.storyboard the segue with the action are the array of images on the technology view controller

Comment: Ok, I have had a look at your project, there are a few issues happening. Your `setTechnology` function is working due to you are trying to dismiss a viewController which is not dismissable. With your segue and image name correlation, the code provided in my example, without the dismiss, is the answer you need but when you use `UIImage(named: technology)` you need an asset called by that identification! ALL of your segues have `showTechnology` and you are using that as the image name, so even if you did have an image called `showTechnology`, all actions would be the same!

Comment: Think you need to look at what you are trying to achieve and look at the tag route which I explained before.

Comment: I have put my answer back to the 2 options as they are both relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You could use three separate IBActions that all call the same function with the UIImageView number as a parameter.

```
func setTechnology(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, imageViewNumber: Int) {
    dismiss(animated: true) {

    var imageView: UIImageView!

    if imageViewNumber == 0 {
        imageView = self.technologyView.technologyImageView
    } else if imageView == 1 {
        imageView = self.technologyView.technologyImageViewTwo
    } else {
        imageView = self.technologyView.technologyImageViewThree
    }

    if let technology = segue.identifier{
        self.persona.technology = technology
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: technology)
    }

    //animating scale up of image
    let scaleUp = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 0.1, y:0.1)
    imageView.transform = scaleUp
    imageView.alpha = 0

    //animating bounce effect 
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: [], animations: {
        imageView.transform = .identity
        imageView.alpha = 1
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

And then call this function from inside the three separate IBActions.

```
@IBAction func tappedButtonZero(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.setTechnology(segue: segue, imageViewNumber: 0)
}

@IBAction func tappedButtonOne(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.setTechnology(segue: segue, imageViewNumber: 1)
}

@IBAction func tappedButtonTwo(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.setTechnology(segue: segue, imageViewNumber: 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could drag multiple buttons to your `@IBAction` and assign a unique `tag` value to each button. Then, use a switch statement to do whatever's unique to the button you pressed.

```
@IBAction func tappedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        print("one")
    case 2:
        print("two")
    case 3:
        print("three")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```